# How to change Dyalog's UCMD source folders on Linux

Tags: configuration, apl, dyalog

On Windows the answer is Options>Configure>"User commands"

Answer (score 1):

In a session:

```
      ]settings cmddir ,folder -permanent
```

And under program control:

```
      ⎕SE.SALT.Set'cmddir ,folder -permanent'
```

`,` adds a folder to the setting -  omitting it will overwrite the configuration instead.